# Sunny coffee house in Vienna

Tags: recommendations, vienna, food-and-drink

I would like to find a sunny coffee house in Vienna. That is one with enough glass in the roof or huge windows, so that on sunny winter days one can sit inside and still enjoy the sunshine.

Any recommendations? Ideally reachable from Subway/tram station Schottentor with public transportation.

Comment: Right now (close to winter solstice) the sun stays low enough so that you can choose any cafe looking south with a wide open area in front of it. If you're looking for some with big windows, take one at the beginning of Währinger Straße (that's the street beginning at Schottentor which all the tram lines starting underground at Schottentor take).

Answer (score 14):

The best suggestion that comes to mind is the Palmenhaus at the Burggarten. [image: Palmenhaus at the Burggarten].
<sup>Image source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AT-13768_Palmenhaus_Burggarten_05.JPG)</sup>

It's a café-brasserie-bar with a huge conservatory facing south-west. Even better, it has a large expanse of open ground (the Burggarten) in front of it, so the sun is not blocked by buildings even when it's low in the sky.

You can reach it by public transport from Schottentor by taking a southbound tram along the Ringstraße. Alight at Burgring, and the Palmenhaus is less than 100m away through the Burggarten.

Comment: "that would do it"  :)

Comment: It also has a pretty awesome Butterfly House which you can walk around in (as you can see, there's the entrance on the left of you zoom in)

Comment: But keep in mind that this picture is looking south-west. This means that the building behind the café is to the south of it. I'm not sure whether the sun gets high enough so that you get several consecutive hours of sunlight a day. But for sure there will be a lot of natural daylight.

Comment: @martin.koeberl No, the photographer is facing east, and the conservatory itself is facing south-west. [Here's an aerial view](http://i.imgur.com/7WBzLOL.png). The building in the background is the Albertina museum, and lies to the north-east of the café.

Comment: @Pont: Oh, damn, right. On my mental map I always put the Palmenhaus on a different side of Burggarten.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out the roof terrace bar on top of the '25 hour Hotel' at the end of lerchenfeldstrasse, 2 mins from Volkstheater metro and Museum Quartier. Nice views and a large balcony terrace.